# getting the multilingual alias. - drupal_get_path_alias

Tags: path, drupal-7, multilingual

I am trying to create a multilingual site the following code outputs my main menu, however the links are retained as english when the user switches languages.  I am using i8ln and entity translate. The two nodes exist so how do I retrieve the link for the multilingual page? I thought drupal_get_path_alias() would work by switching in the language. Code below.

```
<ul id="main-menu">


      <?php

foreach($main_menu as $index)
{

dsm($index);


$path = file_create_url($index['menu_icon']['path']);

$class = $index['attributes']['class'][0];

$current = "node/".$node->nid;

$lang_name = $language->language ;

$linky = drupal_get_path_alias($index['href'], $lang_name);

if ($current == $index['href']) {
$class .= " selected";
};
   print '<li class="'.$class.'">
   <img src="'.$path.'" alt="icon-rockfall" />



   <a class="'.$class.' textlink" href="/'.$linky.'">'.$index['title'].'</a></li>';


   }


            ?>
         </ul>
       </nav>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I resolved it with the code below:

```
<?php
  global $language;
  $url = url('node/1', array('language' => $language));
?>
```

Use the global $language object available.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php
    global $language;
    $url_nodo = url('node/' . $id_nodo, array('language' => $language));
    $url_path = drupal_get_path_alias($url_nodo);
?>
```